# Compare nsdate from server and local nsdate

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have two date in string format :-

1. Server Timestamp = "2015-09-26T13:37:20.000Z";
2. Local Timestamp(converted into UTC format) = "2015-09-26T13:57:44.000+0000";

Code to convert local date into UTC format is :-

```
NSDateFormatter* df_utc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [df_utc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
            [df_utc setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"];

NSString* ts_utc_string = [df_utc stringFromDate:Localnsdate];

// NEED TO CONVERT LOCAL DATA INTO NSDATE INTO NSSTRING BECOZ SERVER DATA I AM GETTING IS IN STRINGFORMAT
```

I want to compare both the local and server data and want to detect which date is early.
But when I try to convert those string into `nsdate` I am not getting `nsdate` as nil.
Please help me.

Comment: Why is the local timestamp in a string that needs converting? You can get the local timestamp as an `NSDate` simply by doing `NSDate *localTime = [NSDate date];`. No need for a string.

Comment: @rmaddy i just want to compare local time and server time. but for that i need to convert both the date into UTC format or any same format such that i can compare both.

Comment: As I said, you don't need to convert local time. You just need to convert the time string from the server.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes but when i try to convert the server time into nsstring it give my null. Is there any way to convert the server time into local

Comment: Try setting the date formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to convert both of the date string to NSDate objects and then compare them using:

```
if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");
} else if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");
} else {
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");
}
```

Comment: The question is about converting the strings to `NSDate` objects, not about comparing the two `NSDate` objects.

Comment: @rmaddy yes.. I am not able to convert the date which is in  string format (local date and server date)  into nsdate (UTC format) and then want to compare.